# Facebook Messenger Bot cannot send message to a given ID not working

Tags: facebook-messenger

I want to send message to a user any time using facebook messenger API. 
I'm using developer version of messaging app and has not submitted for review yet.
We are two friends both as developer in the app. I want when my friend sends message to my page, Bot replies and a copy of message sent by friend comes to my inbox. But when I tried api throws following error.

```
{"error":{"message":"(#100) Parameter error: You cannot send messages to this id","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"HRTLdvidA4u"}}
```

Is there any solution.
Thanks.

Comment: Any solution found ?

Comment: Yes, But you have to approve page_messaging_subscription to enable this feature.

Comment: Did you get it working? I have the same problem - I am a developer of the app and admin of the page that it is associated to but i cant send test message to myself, to my user id.

Comment: Works in development mode but remember 24+1 policy.

Comment: What development mode are you talking about?